# C#- editing excel chart data

Tags: c#, winforms, excel, graph

So right now I am creating excel charts in a c# program that uses a range a cells. Can I edit my code so that I graph all the data in  two columns because I won't know the range. Data is being exported into excel via datagridview so I will know what columns they will go to I just wont know where the cells will stop. I will want to graph everything that is in column a and b and then a graph for everything in column c and d and a graph for everything in e and f.

Here is my code with the ranges:

```
Excel.Application xlApp;
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
        xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;

        for (i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.RowCount - 1; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j <= dataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1; j++)
            {
                DataGridViewCell cell = dataGridView1[j, i];
                xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = cell.Value;
            }

        }

        Excel.Range chartRange;

        Excel.ChartObjects xlCharts = (Excel.ChartObjects)xlWorkSheet.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
        Excel.ChartObject myChart = (Excel.ChartObject)xlCharts.Add(10, 80, 300, 250);
        Excel.Chart chartPage = myChart.Chart;

        chartRange = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1", "B65");
        chartPage.SetSourceData(chartRange, misValue);
        chartPage.ChartType = Excel.XlChartType.xlColumnClustered;

        Excel.Range chartRange1;

        Excel.ChartObjects xlChart1 = (Excel.ChartObjects)xlWorkSheet.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
        Excel.ChartObject myChart1 = (Excel.ChartObject)xlChart1.Add(10, 80, 300, 250);
        Excel.Chart chartPage1 = myChart1.Chart;

        chartRange1 = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("C1", "D65");
        chartPage1.SetSourceData(chartRange1, misValue);
        chartPage1.ChartType = Excel.XlChartType.xlColumnClustered;

        Excel.Range chartRange2;

        Excel.ChartObjects xlChart = (Excel.ChartObjects)xlWorkSheet.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
        Excel.ChartObject myChart2 = (Excel.ChartObject)xlChart.Add(10, 80, 300, 250);
        Excel.Chart chartPage2 = myChart2.Chart;

        chartRange2 = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("E1", "F65");
        chartPage2.SetSourceData(chartRange2, misValue);
        chartPage2.ChartType = Excel.XlChartType.xlColumnClustered;
```

Comment: I want to change my code that creates the excel chart. I don't know the chart range. I just know I want to populate the chart from everything in column a and b, a graph from column c and d, and a graph from column e and f.

Comment: Well, could you tell me what you achieved to do and what's blocking you? Right now it's not really a question...

Comment: Well what I've achieved is my working code above that creates the excel chart from the excel spreadsheet ranges but  I cant use the ranges of the exact cell locations because I won't know where it stops. This program will constantly be adding more data to the excel spreadsheet so the new data must be added to the graphs.

Comment: This program runs every evening and adds a new build to the spreadsheet so the new build must be added to the graph. But I know that everything in column a and b must be graphed together same thing with c and d and e and f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to do that:

```
chartRange = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1", "B" + dataGridView1.RowCount);
```

Doing that, you will get all the range you want